# Insert array of JSON objects in db2 stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I'm trying to pass an array of JSON objects to the Stored procedure, so that each JSON object will be stored in a single row of the table.

for an example: 
to insert a single entry: `INSERT INTO SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME (id,name) values (1,'my_name')`

now i have an array of such data which I want to push into stored procedure to get all data inserted into table without hitting SP again and again.

array example: `[{id:1,name:'name1'},{id:2,name:'name2'}]`

now i can have number of object to be stored.

so either i would hit the SP again and again to push each object individually or i would pass whole array and run a loop inside a stored procedure to get it done.

I have DB2 10.5 LUW with fixpack 7 installed and using node.js

Comment: Now you have to ask a question and to provide some source code you already tested...

Comment: If i would know that, i could have done that anyhow...

Answer (score 0):

DB2 10.5 does not support JSON as a native data type, so you won't be able to do this without passing the JSON as a VARCHAR and having the stored procedure parse/deconstruct the JSON.  The obvious way to do this would with a C or Java stored procedure.

That said, there are some JSON capabilities (see [this series of articles](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1306nosqlforjson1/index.html) for more details, but this is almost certainly not what you want.